# Is there a way to map output of AES algorithm to hex display on nexys a7?

Tags: encryption, verilog, fpga, xilinx

I am implementing the AES algorithm on a Nexys A7 and I don't understand how to display the output. How can I display the first 4 bytes or the last 4 bytes of the output on the hex display? I've included the testbench and the AES module.

```
include "round_last.v"

module AES(key_out, state_out, key_in, state_in);
input [0:127] state_in, key_in;
output [0:127] state_out, key_out;

wire [0:127] key1, key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8, key9;
wire [0:127] s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s_out;


assign s0 = state_in ^ key_in;

//assign state_in = 128'h00_11_22_33_44_55_66_77_88_99_aa_bb_cc_dd_ee_ff;
//assign key_in = 128'h00_01_02_03_04_05_06_07_08_09_0a_0b_0c_0d_0e_0f;

round r1(key1, s1, 4'h1, s0, key_in); //round(rkey, state_out, rn, state, prkey) ;
round r2(key2, s2, 4'h2, s1, key1);
round r3(key3, s3, 4'h3, s2, key2);
round r4(key4, s4, 4'h4, s3, key3);
round r5(key5, s5, 4'h5, s4, key4);
round r6(key6, s6, 4'h6, s5, key5);
round r7(key7, s7, 4'h7, s6, key6);
round r8(key8, s8, 4'h8, s7, key7);
round r9(key9, s9, 4'h9, s8, key8);
round_last r10(key_out, state_out, 4'hA, s9, key9);
endmodule 
`timescale 1ns/1ps
```

`include "AES.v"

```
module AES_tb;

reg [0:127] state, key;
wire [0:127] s_out, k_out;

always@(state);
AES crypt(k_out, s_out, key, state);

initial #50 ;
initial
begin 
$monitor("a = %h, b= %h, c= %h, d=%h", state, key, s_out, k_out);
$monitor("a = %h, b= %h, c= %h, d=%h", state, key, s_out, k_out);
$dumpfile("AES_tb.vcd");
$dumpvars(0, AES_tb);
//#0 state = 128'h00_04_12_14_12_04_12_00_0C_00_13_11_08_23_19_19 ;
//#0 key =  128'h0F_15_71_C9_47_D9_E8_59_0C_B7_AD_D6_AF_7F_67_98 ;
//#0 state = 128'h54_77_6F_20_4F_6E_65_20_4E_69_6E_65_20_54_77_6F;
//#0 key = 128'h54_68_61_74_73_20_6D_79_20_4B_75_6E_67_20_46_75;
#0 state = 128'h00_11_22_33_44_55_66_77_88_99_aa_bb_cc_dd_ee_ff;
#0 key = 128'h00_01_02_03_04_05_06_07_08_09_0a_0b_0c_0d_0e_0f;
$finish;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: what are you supposed to see in your simulation and what did not work? BTW, `#0` has a very special meaning and you should have a very good reason for using it. Do you? Most likely you needed something like #1 or bigger.

Comment: I am attempting to encrypt a 128-bit hex string. Everything is working as far as encrypting but I'd like to display the cipher text on the seven segment display somehow.

Comment: so, replace #0 in your tb with #10 and see if it helps.

Answer (score -2):

[Instant SoC](https://www.fpga-cores.com/instant-soc/) has a 7-Segment driver. i.e. you can do that with a couple of C++ lines. With the timer etc it is very easy to scroll your result on the display.

Use the class [FC_IO_SegmentDisplay](https://www.fpga-cores.com/ISOCCL/html/class_f_c___i_o___segment_display.html). There is an example how to use it.

I have used this on the Nexus A7 board and it is very easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to this. I appreciate all the help.  Does Xilinx Vivado compile or incorporate the c++ file automatically when you add it as a design source?

Comment: @Holminge the question is about verilog, not about c++. Besides, a *couple of lines* is a very vague statement.

Comment: @RogerB Instant SoC is a tool that creates HDL from C++. You compile the C++ with instant SoC and that generates VHDL and a verilog header file that you add to your Vivado project.

Comment: @Serge. Instant SoC generates an HDL module that you use in your verilog code like any other IP. And I understand the problem was to use the Led segment-display on Nexus A7 and Instant SoC has support to generate segment led driver.

Comment: I see, thank you. I will attempt that. Who knew HDL's were hard to master? (joke!)